# How would I implement this protocol in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

If I have a class named myIntersitital, how would I implement this objective c protocol in it. Any tips would be appreciated. I just get 'does not conform to protocol' error.

**Swift:**

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds
class myInterstitial: GADCustomEventInterstitial{
//... implements here
}
```

**Objective-c Protocol:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADCustomEventInterstitialDelegate.h"
#import "GADCustomEventRequest.h"


    @protocol GADCustomEventInterstitial<NSObject>

    @property(nonatomic, weak) id<GADCustomEventInterstitialDelegate> delegate;


    - (void)requestInterstitialAdWithParameter:(NSString *)serverParameter
                                         label:(NSString *)serverLabel
                                       request:(GADCustomEventRequest *)request;

    - (void)presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;

    @end
```

Comment: Did you add GADCustomEventInterstitial to the "xxx-Bridging-Header.h"? While you press cmd and click GADCustomEventInterstitial, where is it exact location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to list a superclass (or NSObject) before the protocols. I would also recommend you capitalize your class names.

```
import Foundation

class MyInterstitial: NSObject, GADCustomEventInterstitial {

    var delegate: GADCustomEventInterstitialDelegate?

    func requestInterstitialAdWithParameter(serverParameter: String!, label serverLabel: String!, request: NSObject!) {
        // implementation here
    }

    func presentFromRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```